# Watch a variable in an object in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, watch

I need to be notified on change of some variables in the `Object`. But the `Object` is not predefined. I tried the below `Watchers`

[watchjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/watchjs)

[watchObject](https://www.npmjs.com/package/watch-object)

[gawk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gawk)

In all these watchers, the `Object` are predefined.

I need a functionality like the below.

```
//Initially the Object will be empty.
var ex1 = {      
};

//Will watch for variable1 in that Object
watch(ex1, "variable1", function(){
    console.log("Variable1 changed");
});

//Changing or Adding a variable1 in Object. Now the above watch should trigger.
ex1 = {
    variable1 : "Hai",
    variable2 : "Hello"
}
```

Any `Watchers` to do so or any tweaks?

Comment: You’re not changing anything about the object in your example; you’re creating an entirely new object and discarding the old one. You can use a debugger to watch a variable.

Comment: eye opener comment.. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting below as it might help some guys like me.

I achieved this by using [assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

```
//Initially the Object will be empty.
var ex1 = {      
};

//Will watch for variable1 in that Object
watch(ex1, "variable1", function(){
    console.log("Variable1 changed");
});

//Changing or Adding a variable1 in Object. Now the above watch got triggered.
var ex2 = {
    variable1 : "Hai",
    variable2 : "Hello"
}

Object.assign(ex1, ex2);
```

Comment: `assign` does not assign the new Object to the existing one, as you say. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign "The Object.assign() method is used to copy the values of all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object. It will return the target object."  Copying the value of a property is not the same as copying the object, by which the common understanding is that the object reference is copied (as in the final line of code in your original question).

Comment: thanks Neek. updated the answer. my wordings are wrong, but what I done is correct I hope

Comment: Yes absolutely, I just wanted to drive home the point that Ryan made. It's an easy trap to fall into when not thinking clearly about objects and references.  `ex.variable1 = 'Hai';` is very different to `ex = { variable1: 'Hai' };`. Thanks for your understanding :)